# Accessing gmail folders with mbsync

Tags: backup, sync, gmail

I am trying to create a replica of the `"[Google Mail]/All Mail"` folder in my gmail account using mbsync. Using `Pattern *` in the rc-file mbsync can see all the folders (lables) that I have created and the Inbox folder as well (I have also successfully synced these to my local system) but there is no trace of any `[Google Mail]/` or `[Gmail]/` folders. How can I get mbsync to see and sync them? My conf looks lite this:

```
IMAPAccount user@gmail.com-account
Host imap.gmail.com
User user@gmail.com
Pass *********
UseIMAPS yes
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

IMAPStore user@gmail.com-master
Account user@gmail.com-account

MaildirStore user@gmail.com-slave
Path /var/emailbackup/mailboxes/user@gmail.com/
Inbox /var/emailbackup/mailboxes/user@gmail.com/Inbox

Channel user@gmail.com-channel
Master :user@gmail.com-master:
Slave :user@gmail.com-slave:
Patterns * "[Google Mail]/*" "[Gmail]/*"
Create Both
SyncState *
```

and I call mbsync using

```
mbsync -c /var/emailbackup/rc-files/user@gmail.com.rc user@gmail.com-channel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` character, replace it by `\[`.

This is an example from my configuration:

```
Patterns "\[Google Mail\]/All Mail" "\[Google Mail\]/Drafts" "\[Google Mail\]/Sent Mail"
```